# java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, constructor, expectations

I have a class : Function Library where I am instantiating the webdriver instance in constructor as below

```
public class FunctionLibrary {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public FunctionLibrary(WebDriver driver)
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver(){
        return this.driver;
    }
}
```

I am accessing the webdriver instance in child class extending super class: function library

```
public class Outlook extends FunctionLibrary{
    public Outlook(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);      
    }

    @Before
    public void testSetUp()
    {
        getDriver().navigate().to("https://google.com");
    }

    @After
    public void closeTest()
    {
        getDriver().close();
    }

    @Test
    public void openOutlookAndCountTheNumberOfMails()
    {
        System.out.println("executed @Test Annotation");        
    }
}
```

when I execute the above piece of junit code
I am getting error as

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

Anybody can let me where I am going wrong

Comment: You don't have exactly one public zero-argument constructor. You have exactly one public one-argument constructor. Where do you think the constructor parameter `driver` will come from?

Comment: BTW: there's no need to use inheritance for this. Use composition.

Comment: Also: you override the value of `driver` passed into the constructor of `FunctionLibrary`. You currently don't need the parameter; your problem will go away if you remove the parameter (and the corresponding parameter to Outlook's constructor too).

Comment: Thanks Andy, It helped me

Comment: Why is there no answer marked correct?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to pass a parameter into the ctor of `FunctionLibrary`, since you simply overwrite its value:

```
public class FunctionLibrary {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public FunctionLibrary()
    {
        this.driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Making this change means you don't need to pass a parameter in from the test class: just remove its constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` on top of the class.

If you use the `@Parameters` correct it will run just fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a public zero-arg constructor. The testing environment doesn't know what to pass to it's constructor, since you require a `WebDriver` object to be passed.

```
public Outlook(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}
```

There, what do you want the testing environment to pass? Instead do something like keep a zero arg constructor, and pass in a WebDriver instance yourself. Something like this should work.

```
public Outlook() {
    super(new FirefoxDriver());      
}
```

Hope this helps.